# "Tesseract couldn't load any languages!" error when run from windows powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, tesseract

When I try using any language with tesseract I'm getting the following
["couldn't load any languages" error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmKcl.png)

I have added the necessary environment variables, and made sure the tessdata directory contains the required file.

[environment variables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgkhu.png)

[tessdata directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FmaC.png)

Note, when I try running it without the language option it works.
([no -l option working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzFVp.png))

I'm note sure what I'm missing or if there's anything else I should be checking for.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I tried reinstalling and it works now.
[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Jwa.png)